# Read Arduino data with shell script fast

Tags: linux, shell, logging, arduino

My Arduino is recording temperature data (datatype float), which I'm trying  to log on my Linux machine. The big problem is the speed of this logging. The Arduino uses a DS1822 to read the temperature, after which I use the

```
Serial.print(temp);
```

command, where temp is the float holding the temperature data. On the Linux machine, I use the following shell script, that collects the data:

```
#!/bin/sh
while [ 1 ]; do
val=$(cat /dev/ttyUSB0);
echo "$val,$(date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")" >> ~test.txt;
sleep 10;
done
```

The main problem with this is that the sleep (delay) has to be quite large; if I use `sleep 1;`, the computer can not receive any data. 
When I use `screen /dev/ttyUSB0`, I can see that the data is received quite fast. 
With my current script, it seems that the Arduino somehow freezes while sending the data. I also tried to build a simpler script (as the DS1822 data conversion also takes some time) with just a resistance measurement, but this is also taking a lot of time when I use the shell script as described above.

*My question is therefore: how can I optimize my Arduino / shell script in order to log the data just as fast as the Arduino can send it?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by disabling the autoreset that the Arduino is performing when a new serial connection is established. To do so, I placed a 10 uF capacitor between RST and GND. Please note that this capacitor has to be removed before uploading code to your Arduino!

After making this modification, I was able to read resistance data at 10 Hz from my Arduino. To do so, the only thing I modified was the sleep command on the bash script, which is now

```
sleep 0.1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `tail -f` will work:

```
tail -f /dev/ttyUSB0 | bash -c 'cat; date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"'
```

Comment: That gives me only one value. I think that the main problem at the moment is that every time I read a value, I open a serial connection, which resets the Arduino (I also read that I can disable that by placing a 10 uF capacitor between RST and GND, but I'm acquiring data at the moment so I can't check). But, thanks anyway!

Comment: I see you solved it - interesting solution ;-) Are you using the 'Breadboard'? And yes, it looks like [tail](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/tail.c) probably reopens the file periodically as well; I thought it would just wait for data with `select`.